# Scan to mail with Exchange Online/Office365

Tags: exchange, smtp, multi-function-printer

A year ago we've migrated from an on-premise IT environment to a Cloud based one, using Office365 and Azure. E-mail has been migrated to Exchange Online.
We have a couple of scanners (MFP) that need to scan and e-mail PDF's.

Until last week, this was working fin with the Exchange Online SMTP relay over port 25 as suggested by MS here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365

Since last week it is not working anymore. I've tested it with Telnet and I can't connect. The firewall is showing the traffic going outbound, but times out because of a lack of response from the server.

I can connect to this server from our other branches without any issue, so I suspect that suddenly the ISP is blocking traffic on port 25 since last week.

What would be a good solution to get this working again? It is not possible to change the port to 587 in Exchange. Using a a mailaccount with authentication is also not possible as the devices don't support modern authentication and legacy authentication has been disabled (and is unsafe).

I can think of all kind of more of less complicated solutions like routing traffic over a VPN to another location or set up a new relay server (in a local region in Azure), but I was wondering how other companies are handling this. We can't be the only company facing this, but I've found very little info on solutions on internet.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "It is not possible to change the port to 587 in Exchange"? Port setting is something you would do on the MFP. Exchange online can accept either port. Contact your ISP too, as they should not block port 25 from a business customer. Check whether O365 blacklisted you (though I think you can still connect on port 25): https://blog.expta.com/2017/01/how-to-confirm-if-your-ip-address-is.html

Comment: Exchange Online smtp connectors are only listening on port 25, not on 587 and there is also no option to change this. Was quite suprised that this is not possible. So changing the port on the MFP won't work then. Or is this setting somewhere hidden in Exchane Online?
I already contacted the ISP. It's in Dubai and there it's very difficult to get things done from your ISP. 
Our IP is not blacklisten by O365 or Spamhaus. Already checked that. And yes, it would be possible to connect with telnet, just not send e-mail.

Comment: If you use option 2 or 3, you must ensure this port 25 is not blocked on your network or by your ISP. And if you cannot use modern authentication, the only way is to contact with your ISP to not block port 25.